# jQuery how to get element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this code below and I want to check for every input (class="Comment-modal-input") if it's not empty - get its closest element (class="svg-icon") which is upper in the hierarchy and add it class "active".

```
<td class="td-comment" style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#0" title="Add Comment" class="comment-modalbttn">
       <svg width="30px" height="30px" class="svg-icon">
         <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0105, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#page')}"></use>
       </svg>
    </a>
    <!-- MBO MODAL -->
    <div>
       <div class="commentmodalcontainer">
           <div class="flex-comment-modal">
              <div class="comment-modal">
                <div class="comment-modal-close"><span>&#43;</span></div>
                  <div class="comment-modal-content">
                    <h2 class="comment-modal-title">Enter Comment</h2>
                    <apex:inputTextarea rows="5" styleClass="comment-modal-input" value="{!line.comment}" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="comment-modal-buttons">
                     <a href="#0">Cancel</a>
                     <a href="#0" onclick="updateJson();">Apply</a>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <!-- END OF MBO MODAL -->
</td>
```

This is the jQuery I'm trying to do:

```
$('.comment-modal-input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val()){
        var icon = $(this).parents('td').closest('.svg-icon');
        icon.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Any help ?

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: try `$(this).closest('td').find('.svg-icon')`

Comment: Also, jquery provides an empty selector. Can update your if condition to `!$(this).is(":empty")`

Comment: @programtreasures - I can't get the element, I'm having problems to get it

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - didn't work

Comment: try to use just `class="comment-modal-input"` instead of `styleClass="comment-modal-input"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a class to an `SVG` you need to use `.attr('class','class you want')`

`.closest('td')` will find the first `td` that contains your `$(this)`.

 `.find('.svg-icon')` will search the `td` and for any element with that class

```
var icon = $(this).closest('td').find('.svg-icon');
icon.attr('class', 'svg-icon active');
```

**demo**

```js
$('.comment-modal-input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    var icon = $(this).closest('td').find('.svg-icon');
    icon.attr('class', 'svg-icon active');
    console.log(icon.attr("class"))
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-comment" style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#0" title="Add Comment" class="comment-modalbttn">
          <svg width="30px" height="30px" class="svg-icon">
          </svg>
        </a>
        <!-- MBO MODAL -->
        <div>
          <div class="commentmodalcontainer">
            <div class="flex-comment-modal">
              <div class="comment-modal">
                <div class="comment-modal-close"><span>&#43;</span></div>
                <div class="comment-modal-content">
                  <h2 class="comment-modal-title">Enter Comment</h2>
                  <input rows="5" class="comment-modal-input" value="{!line.comment}" />
                </div>
                <div class="comment-modal-buttons">
                  <a href="#0">Cancel</a>
                  <a href="#0" onclick="updateJson();">Apply</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF MBO MODAL -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In case of using jQuery 3, addClass would work so no reason to change.

Comment: @StoychoTrenchev That is true, but we can't be sure what version OP is using.

Answer (score -1):

You better get td-comment element as a parent and loop those elements and check if Comment-modal-input under each solves your condition and then add the active class under the current td-comment element.

Also, Comment-modal-input is not the same as in the code: comment-modal-input.

Edited:

I got this minus but I was correct :)
Sorry didn't posted the code.

```js
$('.td-comment').each(function() {
 var $this = $(this),
     commentModalInput = $this.find('.comment-modal-input'),
      icon =  $this.find('.svg-icon');
      
  if (commentModalInput.val()) {
    icon.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-comment" style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#0" title="Add Comment" class="comment-modalbttn">
          <svg width="30px" height="30px" class="svg-icon">
          </svg>
        </a>
        <!-- MBO MODAL -->
        <div>
          <div class="commentmodalcontainer">
            <div class="flex-comment-modal">
              <div class="comment-modal">
                <div class="comment-modal-close"><span>&#43;</span></div>
                <div class="comment-modal-content">
                  <h2 class="comment-modal-title">Enter Comment</h2>
                  <input rows="5" class="comment-modal-input" value="{!line.comment}" />
                </div>
                <div class="comment-modal-buttons">
                  <a href="#0">Cancel</a>
                  <a href="#0" onclick="updateJson();">Apply</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF MBO MODAL -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```